# img click unhides a hidden div. works in jfiddle but not on live site

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have [this Jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3EjM2/91/) on my site.  Works in jfiddle but not live.  why?  Could it be beacuse I took 3 separate code blocks on jfiddle and attempted to use them all on the same live HTML page?  When I load the site page, the (supposedly) hidden Div is fully visible, and clicking the icon (event trigger) neither hides the div nor shows it nor does anything whatsoever.

The code as used on my site:

```
<style type="text/css">
  #divNotifi {
    height: 30px; width: 200px; position:absolute; 
    top: 200px; left: 20px;  display:none
  }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on('click', function(e) {
    var elem = $(e.target).closest('#btnNoti5'),
        box  = $(e.target).closest('#divNotifi');

    if ( elem.length ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#divNotifi').toggle();
    }else if (!box.length){
        $('#divNotifi').hide();
    }
  });
</script>


<a class="icon hide-text" id="btnNoti5" href="#">
  <img border="0" src="videoicon.jpg" />
</a>
<form method="POST">
  <!-- blah blah foo foo big form with 20 buttons and 88 input fields -->
  <div id="divNotifi">
    <table border="0">
      <tr>
        <td class="R1C1">TITLE:</td>
        <td class="R1C2">
          <input type="text" name="title" id="title" size="32"
                 placeholder="Enter the video title">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What happens when you debug?  Do the selectors find the elements you expect them to?  Are there any errors?  Do the `if` conditions behave as you expect them to?

Comment: did you forget to include jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you can simplify your code like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  button = $('#btnNoti5');
  box = $('#divNotifi');

  button.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    box.toggle();
  });
});
```

Secondly, if you have multiple photos to click and text boxes to display, you could encapsulate this into a function like so:

```
function create_button(button_id, textbox_id) {
  button = $(button_id);
  box = $(textbox_id);

  button.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    box.toggle();
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  create_button('#btnNoti5', '#divNotifi');

  // add as many as needed:
  create_button('#btn1million', '#div1million');
});
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3EjM2/94/).

Comment: Thanks to all suggestions.  I was able to simplify the code and after including jQuery everything works great.  +1 to worldask, the universal site header invokes jQuery but some pages (actually many) require distinct, separate invocation and that did the trick here.